Can Sigil be used to edit an ePub file in NOOK?
EPUB & PagePerfect™ eBooks are the standard format for eBooks in the NOOK store.
According to the accepted answer here:

When someone asks me what GUI to use I suggest Sigil. I find that Sigil, unlike it's alternatives, does not add unneeded code to your ePubs which cause bloating, errors, and slower viewing.

Its code is also on github.

Can I use Sigil to edit the text of the ePub file on NOOK of my computer of an book that I have created?  I try editing an ePub in Sigil and it does not work on NOOK. If I create a simple ePub without DRM, is it readable on NOOK.

@beaker This question is not a reccomendation. "What tools do I need to edit a XYZ file?" is an example of an on-topic question.

Okay, my bad :)

This question is similar to: Are there any WYSIWYG editors for EPUB books?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

When you say "edit an ePub file in NOOK", are you asking if you can edit a file while it's still on your NOOK, or is the file on your computer? Does the ebook have DRM applied? Is this a book that you're creating yourself? What sort of editing are you doing to the file? Are you trying to edit the text of the book, or the style sheet, or the images?

@beaker The file on my computer. It has DRM applied It is a book that I am creating. I am editing the text of the book.

I don't know how you're applying DRM, but that's not important. If you can apply it, you can remove it, and Sigil can edit the ePub. NOOKs read compliant ePubs. Sigil produces compliant ePubs. Beyond that, I'm not sure what your actual question is. Did you try editing an ePub in Sigil and it didn't work on your NOOK? Was there an error or was your book rendered incorrectly?

@beaker I try editing an ePub in Sigil and it does not work on NOOK.

please, be more explicit in what you did. First of all: if you create a simple epub without DRM, is it readable on your NOOK? (I understand that you are starting from scratch and not modifying an existing book)

@mau If I create a simple ePub without DRM, is it readable on NOOK.

Sigil produces ePubs that are readable on a NOOK.

@Arunabh so it seems that the problem is in adding DRM to your book. How do you add it? I never tried it (my ebooks are DRM-free), but looking at this old question https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-possible-ways-to-add-DRM-Protection-to-an-ePub-file it seems that you have to interact with Adobe products and pay a lot of money.
